# How to keep scroll position even after hide show item within form in extjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, extjs, scrollbar

I'm having issue with jumping `scroll bar` .I have logic to show Hide section within my `form` dynamically. But whenever I show sections and `scroll` down to last section within form and again dynamically hide first two section scroll just jump and again set to field on which I was.

Actually it is working good that setting focus again to same field where I was, but for a moment it feels like `scroll` jumping and again coming back due hide/show logic.I have used `Ext.suspendLayouts()` and `Ext.resumeLayouts()` within my show/hide code, but still I am seeing a small jumping moment of `scroll bar`. What actually I am missing ?

Answer (score 0):

Add this line after you show the sections.

```
document.getElementById('ID of section you want to scroll to').scrollIntoView();
```